# Select last identity for table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking for the equivalent of Scope_identity() or @@identity in sql server, except for sqllite?

I'd hate to resort to a max select on the id column, but that is plausible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I have never used SQL Server, I am not exactly sure what `@@IDENTITY` does, but if I understand [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) correctly, then [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: you run "select last_insert_rowid();" in the same transaction as your insert, to return it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**last_insert_rowid()**

This function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function. The last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function.

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)